# NationBuilder - How can print a list of the organizations in my nation?

Tags: liquid

I need to print a dropdown with all the organizations in my nation. The values I need are the organization name and the organization´s profile URL. This is on a NationBuilder theme, not using the API.

Comment: I don't know if there is a liquid variable to query the people/organization in my nation, I also couldn't find an example on the docs similar to what I'm  trying to do, which is to list all organizations (or people with the is_organization? flag I think)

Comment: Is this for shopify or jekyll?

Comment: This is on a NationBuilder theme, I think they just don't allow it.